# Anne and Bernard's marbles

Tags: mathematics, probability

Anne and Bernard have between them 100 marbles, Anne the most. Some in each bag of their marbles are red, the rest, though fewer, are blue. If Anne draws at random two marbles from her bag of marbles, the probability that the two marbles are of different colors is preciesely the same as the probability that Bernard draws two marbles at random from his own bag, and they too are of different colors.

How many marbles of each color do Anne and Bernard have?

Comment: Are the chances nonzero (i.e. both Anne and Bernard have one ore more red marbles and one ore more blue marbles)?

Comment: @Bubbler Indeed!

Comment: Then I think that should be in the question. Either that, or the question should explicitly ask for _all_ solutions. Otherwise "Anne has all the red marbles, Bernard has all the blue marbles, and there can be any number of each so long as they add up to 100 and more are red than blue" is a perfectly good but very boring answer.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Better?

Comment: It feels like you're trying a bit too hard to minimize the number of words :-).

Comment: Finding the answer is pretty easy with a computer but also rather unenlightening. Looking at the solutions my computer finds _without_ the adding-up-to-100 constraint, it's not apparent that there's any particular pattern to them. Do you have reason to believe there's a plausible solution that doesn't involve either brute force or guessing very luckily?

Comment: Also, if Anne has e.g. 30 blue and 25 red marbles, swapping the two numbers (25 blue and 30 red) gives another valid answer. Maybe it's cleaner to specify which color has higher (or equal) numbers.

Comment: I found (with a computer) 28 different solutions - are there any further constraints?

Comment: @lxop I get six solutions (modulo red/blue swapping). How do you get 28?

Comment: my 28 are including all red/blue swappings, so could be considered 7. I've just calculated them using numpy - perhaps we have different probability formulae? (i.e., perhaps mine is incorrect)

Comment: This is looking more and more like routine mathematical manipulation plus computer search, which it's hard to see as a _puzzle_ in any meaningful sense. @BernardoRecamánSantos, is there something we're all missing?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Does your "yes" apply to all six solutions? I'm asking because certain identities may reveal two (or maybe three) of the answers, but the rest seem very random.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos so no further information about what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I'll bite.

I find six independent solutions:

> ```
> Anne red | Anne blue | Bernard red | Bernard blue
> _________________________________________________
>    28    |     27    |     24      |      21
>    30    |     25    |     25      |      20
>    34    |     21    |     28      |      17
>    36    |     28    |     21      |      15
>    39    |     16    |     32      |      13
>    44    |     20    |     25      |      11
> ```

For each of these solutions, the total number of marbles is 100, Anne has more marbles than Bernard, and each person has fewer blue marbles than red marbles.

Finally, the likelihood of each person drawing two marbles and them being different colours:

> The probability here is given by the sum of the probabilities `P(red then blue) + P(blue then red)`:
>
> ```
> P(red then blue) = P(red)*P(blue given red)
>
>                  =     Nr           Nb
>                    --------- x -------------
>                    (Nr + Nb)   (Nr + Nb - 1)
>
>                  =        Nr x Nb
>                    -------------------------
>                    (Nr + Nb) x (Nr + Nb - 1)
> ```

> and by symmetry, `P(blue then red)` is the same calculation, so
>
> ```
> P(red then blue) + P(blue then red) =
>                           2 x Nr x Nb
>                    -------------------------
>                    (Nr + Nb) x (Nr + Nb - 1)
> ```

Calculating this figure for both Anne and Bernard separately yields the following probabilities (rounded for display) for each of the above solutions:

> ```
>   Anne   |  Bernard
> ____________________
> 0.509091 | 0.509091
> 0.505051 | 0.505051
> 0.480808 | 0.480808
> 0.5      | 0.5
> 0.420202 | 0.420202
> 0.436508 | 0.436508
> ```

I found these solutions with a simple computer script, but have also confirmed several of them by hand. I also altered my script to operated entirely with integers to avoid potential floating-point problems (though it didn't change the results).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

solving using basics and chances of picking different color depends on the lesser number.

Comment: A picture of hand-written explanation is hard to read and understand. Can you explain in plain text? You can use MathJax to enter math expressions (tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)).

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on "chances of picking different color depends on the lesser number" and the equation $\frac{T-x}{T}=\frac{100-T-y}{100-T}$? I don't think it agrees with my (and lxop's) result of $\frac{2x(T-x)}{T(T-1)}=\frac{2y(100-T-y)}{(100-T)(99-T)}$ using your variables.